# SCSS Extending one class with another

Tags: css, sass

I have this code

```
input {
     border:1px solid black;
     color:#FFF;
}
```

and this one

```
.input {
     padding:0px 5px 0px 3px;
 }
```

how in result in SASS/SCSS to get

```
input.input
```

to apply .input class for input tag (without spaces between!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in scss

```
input {
     border:1px solid black;
     color:#FFF;
    &.input {
         padding:0px 5px 0px 3px;
     }

}
```

will become in css

```
input {
     border:1px solid black;
     color:#FFF;
}
input.input{
    padding:0px 5px 0px 3px;
}
```

Comment: a yes sorry i'll modify, note the `&` before the `.input`